# Create custom role, multisite, add users/sites?

Tags: multisite, user-roles

I have seen similar questions however the one I found asking a question close to this was never answered.

I am attempting to create a role for our support team on our MultiSite install where they can access all sites like a super-admin can, as well as manage/create/edit/delete users and sites across the network.

According to the [Codes on capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#manage_sites) the `manage_sites` and `manage_network_users` should grant these options, or am I not reading correctly? The code for my plugin so far is here:

```
function sqms_add_custom_roles() {
add_role(
    'sqms_support_team',
    __( 'Support Team' ),
    array(
        'delete_others_pages'    => true,
        'delete_others_posts'    => true,
        'delete_pages'           => true,
        'delete_posts'           => true,
        'delete_private_pages'   => true,
        'delete_private_posts'   => true,
        'delete_published_pages' => true,
        'delete_published_posts' => true,
        'edit_dashboard'         => true,
        'edit_files'             => true,
        'edit_others_pages'      => true,
        'edit_others_posts'      => true,
        'edit_pages'             => true,
        'edit_posts'             => true,
        'edit_private_pages'     => true,
        'edit_private_posts'     => true,
        'edit_published_pages'   => true,
        'edit_published_posts'   => true,
        'edit_theme_options'     => true,
        'export'                 => true,
        'import'                 => true,
        'list_users'             => true,
        'manage_categories'      => true,
        'manage_links'           => true,
        'manage_options'         => true,
        'moderate_comments'      => true,
        'promote_users'          => true,
        'publish_pages'          => true,
        'publish_posts'          => true,
        'read_private_pages'     => true,
        'read_private_posts'     => true,
        'read'                   => true,
        'remove_users'           => true,
        'switch_themes'          => true,
        'upload_files'           => true,
        'edit_users'             => true,
        'create_users'           => true,
        'delete_users'           => true,
        'unfiltered_html'        => true,
        'manage_sites'           => true,
        'manage_network_users'   => true,
    )
);

}

function sqms_remove_custom_roles() {
    remove_role( 'sqms_support_team' );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'sqms_add_custom_roles' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'sqms_remove_custom_roles' );
```

The "network" option does not show up in the "my sites" menu, and navigating to /site-new.php just give a no permissions error.

Any advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to the Codes on capabilities the manage_sites and manage_network_users should grant these options, or am I not reading correctly?

Apparently, the capabilities here are not enough. Check out [wp-admin/network.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-admin/network.php#L18).
You'll see it dies if the current user fails the [is_super_admin](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L1520) check. This check gets the `$super_admins` global from [get_super_admins](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L1503) and returns false if the current user is not in that array. It appears a user HAS to be added as a super admin via that option, not just via the appropriate capabilities. That option can be set by manually editing a user (there is a checkbox for it on the user edit screen), or by using the [grant_super_admin](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-admin/includes/ms.php#L691) function.

Regarding the admin bar showing what you want, check out [wp-includes/admin-bar.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/admin-bar.php#L346). You'll see it also runs the is_super_admin check to determine the output of the Network Admin menu.

Comment: Ahh thank you Josh. That makes sense why it wasn't working, I was hoping to find a way to give extra abilities without making them super admins, so I will keep exploring.